# HTML Template Email in Asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, templates, html-email

I have an "payment success" template , Which was done in HTML,CSS,js and images . Now the next phase of requirement involves that , this template need to be send via email to different user by Asp.net SMTP  , i checked on web and cannot able to find a better solution for this, Most of the example has only one or two line of html enclosed with c# code and are send to users.

Is there any nice and easy way to do this?

Comment: Did you try [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sending-email-by-using-email-templates-in-asp-net-webform/) one?

Comment: Will give a try on this,

Comment: It worked , I could able to send email as above approach, But i am facing problems in sending images along with emails,  Can see only the broken images in gmails

Comment: You are asking about sending emails or formatting template? Please clarify.

Comment: No worries, i got it fixed, Thanks mates